# How to lock background image (UIImageView) when VC autorotate?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, autorotate

I have a UIImageView in role a background image:

```
  lazy var backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
    return UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
  }()
```

I set image on `viewDidLoad`:

```
backgroundImageView.image = (self.router?.dataStore?.image)!
```

When VC autorotate, `backgroundImageView` rotate too. How to lock `backgroundImageView`?